# Convert nested relational model to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I have a data model in MVC5 entity framework in which a post has a category. This category can be nested such as.

```
Top Level: 0
  -> Lower Level: 1
      -> Lowest Level: 2
```

This is represented in my model as:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public CategoryModel ParentCategory { get; set; }

   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I display my post which has (from the above example) category "Lowest Level 2", I would like to display

> "Top level: 0 > Lower Level: 1 > Lowest Level: 2"

somewhere on that page to inform the user where they are.

Problem is I dont have any idea of how to do this. 
Propably really simple (as with all things in lambda) but I don't really know how and my googling skills are really off.

**Edit as per comment question:**
The post is defined as this:

```
public class PostModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CategoryModel Category { get; set; } // a post can only have one category
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is follow the `CategoryModel` relation, and then keep following the Categories `ParentCategory` untill it is null. This is always a 1 to 1 relation.

**More Edit:** 
I was fairly simply able to do this with a TSQL-CTE expression but still no idea how to convert this to lambda.

SQL:

```
;WITH Hierarchy(Title, CatId, LEVEL, CategoryPath)
AS
(
  Select c.Title, c.Id, 0, c.Title
    FROM Categories c
    WHERE c.[ParentCategory_Id] IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.Title, c.Id, H.LEVEL+1, H.CategoryPath+' > '+c.Title
    FROM Categories c
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy H ON H.CatId = c.[ParentCategory_Id]
)

SELECT SPACE(LEVEL*4) + H.Title, *
FROM Hierarchy H
ORDER BY H.CategoryPath
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired output when you have more than 1 child category? The `ChildrenCategories` property is defined as collection.

Comment: See my edit., hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an instance of `CategoryModel` you could write a function that will build a string list with the chain of all titles:

```
private void FormatCategories(CategoryModel model, List<string> result)
{
    result.Add(model.Title);
    if (model.ParentCategory != null)
    {
        FormatCategories(model.ParentCategory, result);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
CategoryModel model = ... // fetch your model from wherever you are fetching it
var result = new List<string>();
FormatCategories(model, result);
```

Now all that's left is to reverse the order of elements in the list and join them to retrieve the final result:

```
result.Reverse();
string formattedCategories = string.Join(" -> ", result);
// At this stage formattedCategories should contain the desired result
```

Comment: This does work, but I was hoping there would be a Lambda solution so that I could get the SQL server to do the work (and not have to bring all the category data to the C# code)..